# Playing, Pausing, etc Spotify Web Playback SDK with Python

Tags: python, flask, spotify

I am using the Spotify Web Playback SDK to create a webpage that can play my music from my Spotify account. I am using an HTML template in Flask to run this code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Spotify Web Playback SDK Quick Start Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Spotify Web Playback SDK Quick Start Tutorial</h1>
  <h2>Open your console log: <code>View > Developer > JavaScript Console</code></h2>

  <h3>PAUSE</h3>
  <script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
        const token = 'BQB93YTT8NKaM-Xhur02dkUUnacErZCZ8usjI-Wqw9E1Z3K2hNckoeQttPOk8ZskHpVCKaH6aBN86v2fBoUFsV_9-DFM0_61yZgBPtXySqXtc7h66dxXZJCLnxHRUBStT9wx2ppGfFK90GMXYrm6hUUt3dwzom4LMbgR';
        const player = new Spotify.Player({
            name: 'Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player',
            getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(token); }
        });

        // Error handling
        player.addListener('initialization_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('authentication_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('account_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('playback_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });

        // Playback status updates
        player.addListener('player_state_changed', state => { console.log(state); });

        // Ready
        player.addListener('ready', ({ device_id }) => {
            console.log('Ready with Device ID', device_id);
        });

        // Not Ready
        player.addListener('not_ready', ({ device_id }) => {
            console.log('Device ID has gone offline', device_id);
        });

        // Connect to the player!
        player.connect();

        window.onclick = myFunction;

        // Pause or Play current song
        function myFunction() {
            player.togglePlay()
        }
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to send some code to the webpage from python that will trigger the play or pause function.

I have tried post methods and other things with flask but they all require the page to reload with the new code. I need a solution that can be used dynamically and after the page has already loaded.

Comment: You're basically talking about AJAX then? You need to send requests to an internal data (i.e. JSON) endpoint in your app, rather than rendering a webpage.

Comment: Possibly, I keep trying to research it, but all I get is "use {{foo}}" but the most I can figure out how to do is replace that with my post method in python. but that requires it to be done at page loading.

Comment: I found the flask docs have some info on this. Example code [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/1.0.2/examples/javascript) linked from bottom of doc page [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/jquery/).